# closing a colorbox.js window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I used colorbox.js in my php page to show the list of items the user has chosen;
i added a save button in the bottom of the page; i want to close the colorbox window after saving the info;

I tried the following:

```
$.fn.colorbox.close();
$(".example5").colorbox.close();
```

i get the colorbox is undefined;

here's my code:

### prList.php:

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".example5").colorbox();

            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Testtesttest.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

<body>
       <div id="listDetails">
          <p><a href="form.php?prodId=<?php echo $roow[0]; ?> class="example5">ViewTable</a></p>
       </div>
</body>
```

### Form.php:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border:1" >
            <tr class="catH">
                <td>aa</td>
                <td>bb</td>
                <td>cc</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="3">

                     <div align="center" style="height:20px;">
        <a href="#" style="color:#000000;" id="cboxSave" class="lbAction" rel="deactivate" onclick="savePurchase();">Save </a>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### savePurchase():

```
function savePurchase(){
    ....................
    $.fn.colorbox.close();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [docs](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) helps:

```
$.colorbox.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following FAQ entry:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#jquery

It sounds like you are d.  If you are trying to call that from within an iframe, you should be using the following format:

parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();